# Allow interaction with open modal (React and Material UI)

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, frontend

I have a problem regarding the frontend.
I'm using the Material UI in react and when I open the modal, the rest of the page stays locked until I close the open modal.
I've already used the ""hideBackdrop" property, but the background is still locked.
Does anyone know of a way to unlock the background with open modal?

At this moment the modal component call looks like this:

```
<Dialog
  hideBackdrop
  maxWidth={maxWidth}
  open={open}
  onEnter={onEnter}
  onClose={onClose}
  PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
  aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the Popper element instead ?

https://material-ui.com/components/popper/

According to the documentation

"Popper can be used to display some content on top of another.."

Comment: hello,

Thanks for the sugestion. It could also be a popper.
Would it be better to use Popper instead of Dialog to create draggable windows like windows?

Comment: Hey, i am sorry for the late response, hopes it is still relevant.

I think that in your case a Popper will be suitable.

I think that you can make a Popper draggable as well, but i dont think it exists just out og the box